# Php echo printing html tags as it is in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm displaying description on a page which has html tags in it but it is printing html tags as it is. I want html tags to work. As you can see in screenshot http://prntscr.com/9tqply .

My code is below. This project is in wordpress and I've made custom templete to display record.

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
    <?php if (isset($_GET['id']) && $row->id == $_GET['id']) { ?>
        <h1><?php echo $row->name; ?></h1>
        <?php echo $row->description; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: use `echo  htmlspecialchars_decode($row->description);`

Comment: it's displaying this now http://prntscr.com/9tqws1

Comment: Is there `<pre></pre>` surrounding the HTML in the page source?